# Memory allocation for multi-dimensional std::vector (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

Lets we have

```
std::vector <std::vector <int>> myVec;
myVec.resize(100);
myVec[0].push_back(1);
myVec[0].push_back(2);
```

When I break the program with a breakpoint, I see that both size and capacity of each *myVec[]* is zero. Additionally, when I try to access `myVec[0][0]`, it gives *access violation error*. How this could be?

P.S.: I am using VS 10

Comment: should you also `myVec[0].resize`?

Comment: Besides this being invalid syntax, where do you breakpoint it, and where do you access `myVec[0][0]`? If you access it after the first `push_back` then it should be fine. @Dan he doesn't need to since he's doing `push_back`

Comment: @Dan: But I already use `push_back()` which allocates memory.

Comment: @Shibli Please post your actual code. This can't be it because `<std::vector int>` won't compile.

Comment: I just added < > around int to make it compile and this works fine in my VS2010.  Btw, just so we are on the same page, this isn't multi-dimensional vector.  This is a vector of vectors, not exactly the same thing.  If you want true multi dimensional array-based storage, you would have to use one of Boost libraries

Comment: @DXM: Won't vector of vectors does the same thing considering I don't need somehing sophisticated?

Comment: At which point you have tried to access myVec[0][0], before or after the `push_back`?

Comment: @Shibli: Just making sure you understand the difference, but yeah, you are free to use whatever makes sense for you.  Multidimensional arrays are sometimes nicer because they use one continuous block of memory where as N by M vector of vectors will allocate M + 1 blocks of memory, but now we are talking optimization which shouldn't be a concern for 99% of cases. For more on the difference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet seems to be perfectly correct. If you have problems with *access violation*, your problem is somewhere else.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> myVec;
    myVec.resize(100); // inserts 100 empty vectors into myVec
    myVec[0].push_back(1);
    myVec[0].push_back(2);
    cout << myVec[0][0] << ' ' << myVec[0][1] << endl;
    myVec[99].push_back(3);
    cout << myVec[99][0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 2
3
```

If someone is confused by using resize for filling empty vector, check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/)

Hope this helps ;)